# mod_rewrite .htaccess subdomain redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I spend the last 2 days searching and learning about .htaccess to redirect all subdomains to a user folder
without changing the url, but i keep having 3 little problems. I really would appreciate some help

problem 1)

If i go to `http://www.example.com/users/foo` it automatically redirect
the url to `http://foo.example.com/` but if i go to `http://www.example.com/users/foo/dashboard.php` 
it does nothing, instead of redirecting to `http://foo.example.com/dashboard.php`

this is the code i use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /users/(.+)/\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

problem 2)

if i go to `http://foo.example.com/dashboard.php`

it gets its information from `http://www.example.com/users/foo/dashboard.php`

but if i type `foo.example.com` in the address bar (in firefox) it (sometimes) automatically redirect
to `www.foo.example.com`, can i prevent the `www` prefix?

this is the code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /users/%1/$1 [L]
```

problem 3)

the campaign website is locaded in the folder `http://www.example.com/website` but should be
visible on the url `http://www.example.com/` (like i get the information from `http://www.example.com/users/foo`
on the url `http://foo.example.com/`).

Answer (score 0):

About problem one I would just check the host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

About problem second this is a modified rule which I got from the drupal `.htaccess` file:

```
# remove www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%.domain.com{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirect to the subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ user/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

About your third problem check this one here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1 [R=301,L]
```